# How to Conditional Format Full Rows

Tags: excel

Is there a away to format rows of cells, so when data is entered in A1, the rest of row A turns red?  The reds will disappear as each row cell is updated?  Something like this works =IF(A2="","",B2=""), but it only flags reds as you type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A" is not a row.  It is a column.

**Edit**  Perhaps this -- it took me a while to understand what you wrote, even though, in retrospect, it was pretty clear.

An entry in column A highlights the **rest** of the row (up to column V)
An entry in any other cell **removes** the highlight from that single cell:

Formula:

```
=AND($A1<>"",A1="")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: this just hightlights the whole row.  i only want the row to highlight when data has been enetered in the first cell but the rest of the row is empty

Comment: The first formula highlights row 1 with an entry in any cell in row 1.  The second formula highlights row 1 if there is an entry in A1, which is what you first wrote.  Now it seems that you want to remove the highlight if there is an entry in some other cell in row 1.  Is that correct?

Comment: @AHughes  See my edited response for another formula, depending on what you really want

Comment: the table ranges from A:V.  What I would like to happen is once data is put into say A2, the rest of that row goes red.  As data is put into cells across that row, the red disappears.  So you can see blanks across the table easily.

Comment: @AHughes See the last Edits to apply to any row within the range A:V

Comment: this doesnt seem to do anything?

Comment: @AHughes It seems to work properly here.  I will add images to the post and you can then indicate the difference between what I have thought you want, to what you really want.

Comment: @AHughes  OH wait, maybe you only want the highlight to disappear in the cells that have data, and not in the entire row

Comment: this worked a treat, thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: @AHughes Since it worked, could you please mark my response as the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to highlight the whole row if only column A contains a value. If any other cell contains a value, the highlight shall disappear.

Select the desired rows and create a conditional format with this formula:

```
=AND(LEN($A1)>0,COUNTA(1:1)=1)
```

[image]

Comment: this is close to what i want, however, the highlight sould only disappear from a cell if data has been enetered in that paritcular cell.  so you can see what cells are still blank in any given row.  its a quality check

Comment: You can still use @tevlyn's solution, but instead of checking for COUNTA(1:1)=1, you need to check if the current cell is blank.

Comment: can u put that in a formula?